# "yearmonthday" added to bibliography when using apa6 with biblatex and biber backend

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa6

I am trying to use the apa6 package with a more extensive version of this document:

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper, english]{apa6}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@ARTICLE{bradley1990startle,
  author = {Bradley, Margaret M and Cuthbert, Bruce N and Lang, Peter J},
  title = {Startle reflex modification: Emotion or attention?},
  journal = {Psychophysiology},
  year = {1990},
  month = {11},
  day = {3},
  volume = {27},
  pages = {513--522},
  number = {5},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{MWE}
\shorttitle{MWE}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{SO}

\leftheader{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some more text before the bibliograpy and a citation \parencite{bradley1990startle} of course.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However when compiling with latex I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...
```

When I continue compiling with biber main Biber this error pops up:

```
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
```

After the last compile with pdflatex I do get output, however some strange text appears in the bibliography:

[image: The Bibliography with the (yearmonthday) text.]

Following the topic ([Xelatex, Biblatex: biber.exe not working properly (IPC::Run) error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/xelatex-biblatex-biber-exe-not-working-properly-ipcrun-error)) I have tried to compile with `biber -f main`, which didn't help either.

I also tried adding:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
```

which didn't help either. I also tried filling out the day and month fields, but even if those are present the text (yearmonthday) still shows up in the bibliography. How do I get rid of that (yearmonthday) text in the bibliography? What does the error about the undefined control sequence `\mkbibdataapalongextra` mean?

All files including the complete log can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i5w1eagntme109k/sG4aKvrKtD).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The macro `\mkbibdataapalongextra` is defined in the language specific files `american-apa.lbx`, `austrian-apa.lbx`, etc., so if these are not loaded correctly then that macro is not defined, which leads to the issue you observed.

Be default, `biblatex` does not know to load `american-apa`, which is why you need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`. However, it seems that you also need to tell `babel` to load american explicitly . I wrote "it seems" because I have not investigated in-depth, so I cannot say I fully understand the interdependence. However, the following code fixes your problem (I took the liberty of simplifying your MWE):

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}


\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@ARTICLE{bradley1990startle,
  author = {Bradley, Margaret M and Cuthbert, Bruce N and Lang, Peter J},
  title = {Startle reflex modification: Emotion or attention?},
  journal = {Psychophysiology},
  year = {1990},
  month = {11},
  day = {3},
  volume = {27},
  pages = {513--522},
  number = {5},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}


Some more text before the bibliograpy and a citation \parencite{bradley1990startle} of course.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quite weird for me, since biblatex, biber, apa, and english+american babel are all very widely used combinations, that biblatex doesn't know "what to do". Oh well, as long as it makes these components happy...